# Android thread has different ID in DDMS, but prints same ID as the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm using the standard logcat to print a thread's id using

```
Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

When I do this, I'm getting `1` printed out on both the UI thread and on another thread I'm creating, so it appears that I've missed something and not actually creating a new thread.

However, if I check the DDMS they do appear as different threads (both have different ID and Tid values).

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found my mistake. I was logging in the constructor of the thread, which apparently is run from the calling (UI) thread.

Once I logged this same thing from the run() method, I got a different thread Id.

Comment: You might want to remove the question then. It's not going to be very helpful for anyone else.

Comment: It would have been helpful for past me.